# The type or namespace name does not exists. But only on the build server

Tags: c#, build-error

So, this is a really weird one...
From my development machine, I'm able to build a solution.
When doing a check-in, the build server validates the changes and throws the following message:

> ConnectorController.cs(16,20): Error CS0234: The type or namespace
> name 'Emails' does not exist in the namespace 'WebDashboard' (are you
> missing an assembly reference?)

The funny thing is: In the same project there is a `WebDashboard.Emails`:

```
namespace WebDashboard.Emails
{
...
}
```

Is there anything that I'm not seeing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.
I only checked in the relevant files for the work item and did not take into account the .csproj file in which the references are set.

After checking in the .csproj file, everything compiled just fine

Comment: You can accept your own answer, to let others know that the issue is solved.